# Cannot read property 'split' of undefined on string in javascript

Tags: javascript

Why am I getting the error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined
```

With the following code?

```
var testing = url.parse(req.url, true);
testing = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(testing.query));
console.log(testing);
testing.q = testing.q.split(' ').join('+');
console.log(testing);
```

The first console.log prints:

```
{q: 'hello world'}
```

The second console.log prints:
The first console.log prints:

```
{q: 'hello+world'} //Which is correct BUT still giving me the error
```

Ex:

```
hello world
```

I want it to split an join the space to be:

```
hello+world
```

Comment: Please show your code for acquiring the initial value of `testing.q`.

Comment: This works just fine on my end ´var testing= {q: "Hello World"};
testing.q = testing.q.split(' ').join('+');´

Comment: according to the error, q isn't being initialized. Have you confirmed that q actually says 'hello world'?

Comment: Updated the code. I am taking a url parameter.

Comment: after line 2, what's in `console.log(testing)` ?

Comment: While I admire the spirit of problem-solving in the comments, the bottom line is you've asked an incomplete question.  Show us an input, the actual output, and explain why/how the actual output differs from the expected output.  The main thing missing here is an input (not merely a description of how you think the input looks)

Comment: I have added the output to the question. Did not realize that was the issue.

Comment: I have added two console.logs to show output.

Answer (score 1):

That is because you are using split() function on the JSON object instead of the 'hello world' string

```js
var obj = JSON.parse('{ "name":"Hello World"}');
obj.name = obj.name.split(' ').join('+');
console.log(obj);
```

Comment: @user10181542 I think you should try the code without JSON.stringify(), I tried JSON.stringify() in my code and I got the same error as you.

Comment: Will give error: TypeError: Cannot convert object to primitive value if you remove stringify()

Comment: After further testing, it looks like the parse stringify is being called twice. The first time split encounters no error and the second time it gives a type error.